# Outlook Ribbon Increase Ribbon Size?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My Outlook Ribbon suddenly shrunk with newest update, and is now harder to read and use. This was on the newest "Office has updates" update.

Comment: Please tell us what version you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You could repair Office: go to Control Panel > Programs and Features. Right click your Office suit and then choose Change. Click Repair.

Office 365 released a new feature: simplified ribbon. You can check [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/deva/2019/05/02/office-365-and-new-outlook-simplified-ribbon/) to see if this is the case for you.